# How to find new/changed/removed files in a folder with python 3.x

Tags: python, file, monitor

I have a tool which adds new files each day at 11pm into a Unix server folder.
I want to write a python script, to be launched at 11.30pm, which find the new files, the removed files and the modified files inside this folder.
The files have unique name "123456_0.csv, 123456_1.csv".
Since the script will be launched manually, I don't want to use the busy wait pattern.
I want to use only python library.

Thank you.

In the following lines my code(I'm new to python):

```
def F_CreateArchive(Time_stamp, Added_Filename, Aux_Filename, Field_Names, File_Extension):
        if not os.path.exists(Added_Filename):
            with open(Added_Filename, 'w', newline='') as arch:
                archive_write = csv.DictWriter(arch, fieldnames=Field_Names, delimiter=';')
                archive_write.writeheader()
                folder_files = glob.glob(File_Extension)
                for each_folder_file in folder_files:
                    md5file = hashlib.md5(open(each_folder_file,'rb').read()).hexdigest()
                    archive_write.writerow({'TIMESTAMP': Time_stamp, 'FILENAME': each_folder_file, 'ACTION': 'added', 'MD5': md5file})
        return 0
    def F_CheckAdded(Time_stamp, Added_Filename, Aux_Filename, Field_Names, File_Extension): 
        dict_added_archive = {} 
        dict_folder_file = {} 
        folder_files = glob.glob(file_extension)
        for each_file in folder_files: 
            with open(each_file, 'rb') as file:
                dict_folder_file[each_file] = hashlib.md5(file.read()).hexdigest()

        with open(Added_Filename, 'r') as addfile:
            added_read = csv.DictReader(addfile, delimiter=";")
            for row in added_read:
                if(row['FILENAME'] != ''):
                    dict_added_archive[row['FILENAME']] = row['MD5']
            addfile.seek(0)

        print(dict_folder_file)
        print(dict_added_archive)

        with open(Aux_Filename, 'w', newline='') as aux, open(Added_Filename, 'r') as addfile:
            added_read = csv.DictReader(addfile, delimiter=";")
            aux_write = csv.DictWriter(aux, fieldnames=Field_Names, delimiter=';')
            aux_write.writeheader()
            for filename_folder, md5_folder in dict_folder_file.items():
                if filename_folder in dict_added_archive and md5_folder == dict_added_archive[filename_folder]:
                    print('The file %s hasn\'t been changed.' %filename_folder)
                    for row in added_read:
                        if(row['FILENAME'] == filename_folder):
                            aux_write.writerow(row) 
                    addfile.seek(0)

                elif filename_folder in dict_added_archive and md5_folder != dict_added_archive[filename_folder]:
                    print('The file %s has been modified.' %filename_folder)
                    aux_write.writerow({'TIMESTAMP': Time_stamp, 'FILENAME': filename_folder, 'ACTION': 'added', 'MD5': md5_folder})

                elif filename_folder not in dict_added_archive:
                    print('The file %s is new.' %filename_folder)
                    aux_write.writerow({'TIMESTAMP': Time_stamp, 'FILENAME': filename_folder, 'ACTION': 'added', 'MD5': md5_folder})

            for filename_archive, md5_archive in dict_added_archive.items():
                if filename_archive not in dict_folder_file:
                    print('The file %s has been removed.' %filename_folder)
                    aux_write.writerow({'TIMESTAMP': Time_stamp, 'FILENAME': filename_archive, 'ACTION': 'removed', 'MD5': md5_archive})
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Which flavour of UNIX?  On Linux you can use `pynotify`:  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-notify/0.3.1

Comment: I would to avoid pynotify.

Comment: @MooingRawr the input are the csv files. If the file have been modified, new or removed AND added in a new version, they must be processed. At this moment I just want to understand how to detect these conditions. The output will be the status of the file: new, removed, modified (which means that the file is new but different from the previous version).

Answer (score 1):

- Find deleted files?

  - You may keep track of file names as [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) or in a textfile and  do a diff with current available files
- Find new files ?

  - Same as above
  - Check the [os.stat](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat)(path) : st_ctime , on all files
- Find modified files ?

  - Check the [os.stat](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat)(path) : st_mtime , on all files

Comment: I can't use pickle. Any other options? Thank you.

Comment: Store the file names in a file

Comment: @Rozmol you may accept the answer if it fits your requirements